# Is this a Major Bug in C# ASP.NET Generic Handler Redundant Variables?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

In "C# Generic Handler", Session Variables and Input Params are becoming Duplicate or Redundant.

In C#,

if there is already a Session["X"] variable and

if input to iHttpHandler is "X", then

HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["X"] is

returning concatenated string of both Session and Input FormData from Ajax.

It is not distinguishing the difference.

I was sending data to "c# Generic Handler" from Ajax with FormData("X", "V").

Session already has the variable as "X", Say, Session["X"] is "Z";

in JS:

```
function f(ipaddr) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.set("X", "V");
var url = window.location.origin + "/api/generichandlerapi.ashx";

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
          }
   });

}
```

Inside Handler:

```
string C;

Session["X"] = "Z";

C = HttpContext.Context.Request.Params["X"];
```

C is supposed to have only "V"

but returning

"V,Z"

Comment: Is your session cookie based?

Comment: What does HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["X"] return for you?

Comment: @JohanP, yes. It has cookies.

Answer (score 2):

It is expected behaviour if you use cookies for `Session`. When you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/HttpRequest.cs) for `HttpRequest`, you can see that `Cookies` get added to the `Params` collection:

```
private void FillInParamsCollection() {
        _params.Add(this.QueryString);
        _params.Add(this.Form);
        _params.Add(this.Cookies);
        _params.Add(this.ServerVariables);
}
```

Comment: It is even defined in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.params)

Comment: I may have to try various combinations to see difference in behavior. don't mean to contradict your explanations but, when I sent, QueryString values and formData together, Params was not mixing them. I got the values as I asked individually.  in this "REQUEST" to this Handler, SAME "VARIABLE" value was not used as "COOKIE"s but used as "Session" variable which are "Server Variables". "Formdata" input is not getting set directly to "Session". if formData input and Session have same "KEY" name then getting this problem. Whatever, whatever exists, EXISTS and correct.

Comment: After I had been through several problems due to this, what I conclude is, this may be a BUG or DESIGN FLAW or "Intentional IGNORANCE (only VS design team would know if for a reason)" because it is not in SYNC with the Fundamental principle of "Computing". A VARIABLE in a "CONTEXTUAL SCOPE" should always be UNIQUE and every new value to that "VARIABLE" would override its all earlier values which is not happening here. "VARIABLE" if is "Array" then ARRAY will also have "values" stored in "unique" index. So this must be Genuine Concern of VS.